# Magento2.2.5 issue getting custom attributes to show correctly

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento2.2.5 based website and have edited the list.phtml file to use 3 custom attribute fields for products which we use to format the names in a specific way. My issue is some products have no value in the field we call item_subname_3 so what is happening on the list.phtml file is for items that dont have a value in the item_subname field it is just showing the previous products value over and over again. I tried setting the variable $item_subname_3 to blank before then grabbing the custom attribute value but that does not seem to work. Any suggestions on how I can get the desired outcome? thank you

```
 <?php 
     //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
     $productId = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getId(), 'name');

     //show products names using custom item_name fields
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $_productdata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
     $item_subname = $_productdata->getData('item_subname');
     $item_subname_2 = $_productdata->getData('item_subname_2');
     $item_subname_3 ='';
     $item_subname_3 = $_productdata->getData('item_subname_3');

     echo "<p class='subitemnames'>$item_subname";
     echo "<br/>$item_subname_2";
     if($item_subname_3 != ''){ echo "<br />$item_subname_3"; }
     echo "</p>";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to configure the attributes with "Use in Product Listing" set to "Yes". In that way you could simply access the data of your custom attributes using the `$_product` object with no interference:

```
$_product->getData('item_subname');
$_product->getData('item_subname2');
$_product->getData('item_subname2');
```

If you want to use your approach you can try to reset the `$_productdata` object before loading a new product:

```
$_productdata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->reset()->load($productId);
```

I would recommend the first approach.